# Updating a backbone model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have created a backbone collection like this, which is instantiated in my view

```
define(['underscore','backbone','models/task'],function( _,Backbone,Task) {
    var TaskCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        //Model
        model:Task,
        //api url
        url:'',

        methodToURL: {
        'read': './api/tasks/index',
        'create': './api/tasks/task',
        'update': './api/tasks/task',
        'delete': './api/tasks/task'
        },

        sync: function(method, model, options) {
            options = options || {};
            options.url = this.methodToURL[method.toLowerCase()];

            Backbone.sync(method, model, options);
        },
        //construct
        initialize: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'end';
            this._model = new Task();
            this.fetch();
        },

        comparator: function(a,b) {
            a = a.get(this.sort_key);
            b = b.get(this.sort_key);
            return a > b ?  1
                 : a < b ? -1
                 :          0;
        },

        mark_complete: function(task_id) {
            var task_status = 0;
            console.log(this._model);
            this._model.save({id:task_id,task_status:task_status});
        },

        mark_incomplete: function(task_id) {

        },

        sort_by_status: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'task_status';
            this.sort();
        },

        sort_by_task_tag: function() {
            this.sort_key = 'task_group';
            this.sort();
        }
    });
    return TaskCollection;
});
```

When a dom element is click the mark_complete method on the collection is called.
The "this._model.save({id:task_id,task_status:task_status});" makes a PUT request but the parameters are not being sent.

Comment: The Task is  not instantiating

Comment: The this._model = new Task(); works but shouldn't I normally be able access the model using this.model in the collection context

Comment: Am not having a problem with this._model, am using the chrome console to monitor ajax request and i see is a put request with something like this "request payload" "{"id":"6","task_status":0}"